# Reading multiple uint256 entries from same JSON response using a single ChainLink request

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I need to parse two different uint256 values from the same JSON response to do a simple calculation. I am currently implementing two different requests (one for each of the uint) using the same chainlink test node and jobID

```
 /**
 * Receive the response in the form of uint256
 */ 
function fulfillWeight(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _weight) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    weight = _weight;
}

function fulfillHeight(bytes32 _requestId2, uint256 _height) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId2)
{
    height = _height;
}
```

Is there a way of implementing this without resorting to using two different requests, how could I combine parsing the same json response for the two uint256 values under the same request? would I need to search for a specific Node / JobId that carried this out?  Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, what you're looking for is [Multi-Word (multi-variable) responses.](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/)

As of right now, you do need to know what the job spec of the Chainlink Job is to know what it's going to return, but you can hop into the [Chainlink Discord](https://discord.gg/2YHSAey) and request a node create a generic job for you to get your multiple types back.

This is a brand new Chainlink feature, so documentation is still a little sparse!

Comment: Thanks so much Patrick, sounds really interesting and def going to look into this! At least I can get going with the example in the doc link you posted - hats off to you!